# Trying to expire a jquery.cookie within 3 minutes but no luck

Tags: jquery

I need the cookie to expire automatically after 3 minutes but the following snippet of code from my jquery.cookie.js file is not working. The cookie reads "session" instead of an expiration date.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("leftCol", "collapsed", { expires: date });
```

Comment: Posting source code without any explanatory text begs for closing. Don't think that the title of your question is by any means helpful. *No luck* is not very precise problem description. You could have luck in a casino but not when programming.

Comment: Try re-formating your question so we can read it... The button with binary will turn selected text into code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks OK to me. The following is what I would use for 3 minutes (I don't like calling vars 'date', but that's irrelevant).

```
var expDate = new Date(); 
expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (3 * 60 * 1000)); 
$.cookie("leftCol", "collapsed", { expires: expDate });
```

If your cookie shows "session", you're probably looking at the wrong cookie, or something else has overwritten it before you read it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.cookie("leftCol", "collapsed", { expires: "2m" });
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, no cookie set at all. Using Safari iPad browser.